# Is there a way to REGEXMATCH from a range of cells from A1:A1000 for example?

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Basically, I am trying to find a way to search through a list of phrases and highlight/extract or identify any phrase or cell that contains a phrase or word from a separate column/list.

To put this into context, I have a list of "search terms" that have triggered my Google ads, this list contains phrases or expressions that people have entered into the google search engine.

I also have a list of "negative keywords" that I have used to block ads from showing when certain words or phrases are entered into Google. For example, if I have the word "nursery" in my negative keyword list, then it should stop an ad from showing if someone enters the phrase "best nursery near me"

I have then placed both these lists within an excel spreadsheet in separate columns, so one column has the search terms, and another column has the negative keywords.

What I want to do is search through all the search terms and highlight a cell it if any word or phrase within that cell matches the phrase from the negative keywords list. In the example above, the cell containing the phrase "best nursery near me" would be highlighted or extracted as the phrase "nursery" is in the negative keyword list.

REGEXMATCH in google sheets does do this, however, I don't know of a way for it to select multiple expressions, it does allow multiple expressions but only by doing say (A1|A2|A3), the issue with this is I have over 1000 cells so would want a way to select all of them at once, like (A1:A1000)

here is a link to the Google Sheet, if possible I'd prefer to be able to do it in Excel. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLTswjrpwf2owhX4YxPavUY441WlQsnzv3StoP-ilmc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C:C)), A2:A, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C:C))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("|^", 1, C:C)), A2:A, )),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99)))<>"", 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99))),
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99))))<>"",
 IF(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99)))<>"", 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99))),
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99)))), 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "\s"), A2:A, ), 
 TEXTJOiN("|", 1, C:C)), A2:A, )),,999^99)))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Although this comes really close, is there a way to make it an exact match, for instance in your above screenshot it brings back "aabc", when the phrase in column C is "abc"

Comment: Similar issue, although it returns "abc", if possible id want it only to match if "abc" was a separate word in a phrase, for example, if it was "bbc abc fjd" it would return it as a match, but if it was "bbcabcfjd" it would not return it as a match.

Comment: I think this is pretty close, though I can't test it because the formula is such a beast it crashes every time I put it in lol

Comment: ah one last thing, i feel bad as the formula you have done so far is awesome, but my last issue is that it will return a match if the term in column C starts a phrase, for example in your image above "abcdef" will return a match from "abc"

Comment: thats amazing, one last thing, now this may not be possible, but could it also search for a phrase with a space between, such as "abc bcd" which would be in column C and could return a match, im not explaining this last bit well

Comment: re try, could it return a match from a phrase that contains a space so if in coloumn C i had a dual word phrase like "nursery prices" it could bring a match from "edmonton nursery prices" in column A

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99)))<>"", 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99))),
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, 
 "^"&TEXTJOiN("$|^", 1, C:C)&"$"), A2:A, )),,999^99)))))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umxtt.png

Comment: you sir are amazing at this, there is one last thing that would complete this, can it find that dual word phrase in your example "xbc bcx" if it was in between another so for eample "jkl xbc bcx" or "xbc bcx jkl" or "jkl xbc bcx fgh" would all return a match, i know this may be on the limit of what is possible.

Comment: this is nearly perfect, and is far better than I could have imagined, if I am being super duper picky, would it be possible to remove the end of a match on a dual phrase, the best way to explain this is that in your last example "A xbc bcxs A" (i added an 's' to the end), would still return a match from "xbc bcx"

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` or `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ".$",)` - are formulas for removing last character

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to do this. Don't overcomplicate things.

Say you want to search for a match from a list of cities.

1. Put your list of cities in one tab.
2. Make them into lowercase for easier lookup since search terms are all in lowercase. You can do this by adding a new column and using the LOWER function.
3. Go back to your cell that has the list of search phrases.
4. In any blank cell out of the way (off to the side on the top row is a good place) put this formula:
   CITY LIST FORMULA: =TEXTJOIN("|",1,'vlookup city'!B$2:B$477) (if your tab is named 'vlookup city' and your cities are in column B of that tab)
5. Add a new column next to your search terms, or pick an existing one where you want to put your "match found" info.
6. In that new column, add this formula (if your data starts in row 4 and you put the City List formula in cell G3:)
   =REGEXMATCH(A4,G$4)
7. Fill the formula all the way down your list. You can double-click the little blue square in the bottom right corner of the cell, or grab-and-drag all the way to the bottom of the list.

Ba-ding! It will search for any one of those city names, anywhere in your search phrase.

If the search phrase contains at least one matching term, it will return "True."

You can then add extra features on your formula to make it return something else. For example:
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A4,G$4), "match found", "no match found")

This is a super lightweight solution that won't slow your sheet down too much and is easy to use.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGTn8.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XAIDB98r2CGu7hL3ISirErDPNlgT6lVt-TCG0qI1uTE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What's great is that you can even replace that cell reference in your Regexmatch formula with the Textjoin, and then have a versatile 1-line formula for conditional formatting, which I believe would require an INDIRECT to glue it all together.