# Regexmatch in Google Sheet to identify cells that include any string in another sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a ColumnA where each cell include multiple values separated by comma, eg:

```
Elvis Costello, Madonna
Bob, Elvis Presley, Morgan Stanley
Frank, Morgan Stanley, Madonna Ford,
Elvis Costello, Madonna Ford
```

And I want to identify which rows/cells that includes any of the exact terms in another sheet/column, eg

```
Elvis Presley
Madonna
```

And I found this simple solution using Regexmatch (the last solution on that page) [Is there a way to REGEXMATCH from a range of cells from A1:A1000 for example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577313/is-there-a-way-to-regexmatch-from-a-range-of-cells-from-a1a1000-for-example/57074060#57074060)

> Say you want to search for a match from a list of cities.
>
> Put your list of cities in one tab.
>   Make them into lowercase for easier lookup since search terms are all in lowercase. You can do this by adding a new column and using the LOWER function.
>   Go back to your cell that has the list of search phrases.
>   In any blank cell out of the way (off to the side on the top row is a good place) put this formula: CITY LIST FORMULA: =TEXTJOIN("|",1,'vlookup city'!B$2:B$477) (if your tab is named 'vlookup city' and your cities are in column B of that tab)
>
> Add a new column next to your search terms, or pick an existing one where you want to put your "match found" info.
>
> In that new column, add this formula (if your data starts in row 4 and you put the City List formula in cell G3:) =REGEXMATCH(A4,G$4)
>
> Fill the formula all the way down your list. You can double-click the little blue square in the bottom right corner of the cell, or grab-and-drag all the way to the bottom of the list.
>
> Ba-ding! It will search for any one of those city names, anywhere in your search phrase.
>
> If the search phrase contains at least one matching term, it will return "True."
>
> You can then add extra features on your formula to make it return something else. For example: =IF(REGEXMATCH(A4,G$4), "match found", "no match found")
>
> This is a super lightweight solution that won't slow your sheet down too much and is easy to use.
>
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XAIDB98r2CGu7hL3ISirErDPNlgT6lVt-TCG0qI1uTE/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is that the Regexmatch solution identifies "Elvis Costello" and "Madonna Ford" and I only want to identify cells/rows that includes the exact term to match, ie "Elvis Presley" and "Madonna", ie **whatever is between the commas has to be an exact match with one of the search terms, not just partially right.**

I hope it made sense:)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the answer, still trying to double check if it's correct.

I added \b before and after. So in the example sheet re-posted in the quoted part of my question i changed the cell:

```
Cell B3:
=TEXTJOIN("|",1,'vlookup city'!B$2:B$476)
```

and added another cell like this:

```
Cell B2:
=concatenate("\b(",$B$3,")\b")
```

Still checking if all false flags are removed.
Thanks