# Find same word in 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to automate the analysis of a list by comparing 2 columns to see if they have the same word in them, for example:

[image]

I want to go through the words in Column B and check if they exist in Column C, then return a simple TRUE or FALSE.

I have tried everything I could, really appreciate the help!!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: hey @player0 here you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NXn8rBq2zPHhndGzZXbl7wNEUP4W_sY-vMyOuffVKS0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,MMULT(N(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")="", 0, 
 REGEXMATCH(B1:B, "(?i)"&SPLIT(A1:A, " "))))), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")), 1, 1, 0))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: hey man, seems to be working fine, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

regexmatch  is the function you want to look into. it only works on text, and is case sensitive. So you may need to convert the contents of the cells to all be uppercase.

Here is something you might want to look into
[Is there a way to REGEXMATCH from a range of cells from A1:A1000 for example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577313/is-there-a-way-to-regexmatch-from-a-range-of-cells-from-a1a1000-for-example)

Comment: untrue... `=REGEXMATCH(A1&"", "(?i).+")` ... `&""` will make it that it will work with numeric numbers and `(?i)` will make it case insensitive